# Stripe JS making duplicate requests & new requests on state change

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm using the stripe JS library on my frontend and just setting the token, not actually using the library for anything. Odd thing is that when I load any page stripe will make a bunch of odd requests and lots of them are duplicates. Often it'll look like this:

```
https://m.stripe.com/4
https://m.stripe.com/4
https://stripensrq.global.ssl.fastly.net/s/e
https://stripensrq.global.ssl.fastly.net/s/o
https://m.stripe.com/4
```

Then if I change the page state using the History API it makes all these calls again even though this is a single page webapp. Is this normal?

Comment: Yes, these requests types of requests are not out of the ordinary and look like calls from Stripe's CDN or analytics.

Comment: @henry did you found anything about it?? any solution?

Comment: @RohitS no, they seem to be normal, although I couldn't find anything in the docs about them. I'm taking duck's word for it.

Answer (score 20):

This behavior caught me by surprise, too. If you have `import { loadStripe } from '@stripe/stripe-js` anywhere in your SPA, Stripe will begin phoning home on every page load from the moment your app opens.

### Option 1: Deferring Stripe's library load

As of @stripe/stripe-js v1.4.0, you can use the `/pure` import path, which defers the load of Stripe's library until the app actually calls `loadStripe`:

```
import { loadStripe } from '@stripe/stripe-js/pure';
```

Once you call `loadStripe`, Stripe will continue sending requests to `https://m.stripe.com/4` on every URL change until the browser navigates to a new page through an HTTP request (not through a JavaScript route change) or until the browser reloads.

### Option 2: Disabling Stripe's fraud detection mechanisms

stripe.js makes requests to `https://m.stripe.com/4` as part of its [fraud detection mechanisms](https://stripe.com/docs/disputes/prevention/advanced-fraud-detection). As of @stripe/stripe-js v1.5.0, you can disable this behavior by setting `{advancedFraudSignals: false}`:

```
import {loadStripe} from '@stripe/stripe-js/pure';

loadStripe.setLoadParameters({advancedFraudSignals: false})
const stripe = await loadStripe('pk_test_TYooMQauvdEDq54NiTphI7jx');
```

Note that disabling this feature increases your risk of receiving fraudulent transactions.

### More details

I wrote a blog post about this if you're interested in additional details: https://mtlynch.io/stripe-recording-its-customers/

Comment: Unfortunately it is still impossible to completely disable these trackers. After disabling the `advancedFraudSignals` you can still see events [like these](https://gist.github.com/MaeseppTarvo/72d7462253b38b69d05fdad8ba699ea3) happening when hovering over your Stripe elements:

Answer (score 3):

*EDIT: since writing this, Stripe have updated their library to address these concerns, in large part thanks to @mtlynch's great investigative work. See his answer above for the most up to date answer.*

---

For those wanting to avoid this, it seems that instead of importing the Stripe library as the docs describe:

```js
import { loadStripe } from "@stripe/stripe-js";

// when wanting to actually load Stripe this method is called,
// but `m.stripe.com` was fired on page load, before this was called
const publicKey = "yourPublicKey";
const stripe = await loadStripe(publicKey);
```

...which will automatically call the `m.stripe.com` endpoint, you can dynamically import the library so that this is only called when you actually want Stripe functionality (not on every page, if using redux or vuex, for example):

```js
// create a new async function `stripeJs` that returns the library
const stripeJs = async () => await import("@stripe/stripe-js");
```

```js
// later, we can call this before we need to use the library
// (e.g. in a vuex/redux action)
// STRIPE's TRACKING SCRIPT WILL BE CALLED NOW, RATHER THAN ON LOAD
const { loadStripe } = await stripeJs();
const publicKey = "yourPublicKey";
const stripe = await loadStripe(publicKey);

// example Stripe call
stripe.redirectToCheckout(...)
```

*Fair warning, I'm not sure what `m.stripe.com` does, and so there could be unintended side effects to only importing the library before needing to execute it, but this seems to work in my testing.*

Answer (score 0):

Agree fully with the other answers here re. importing dynamically.

To take things a step further you can consider running your payment processing in a same-origin frame, which means you can force the library to unload once you're finished with it.

```js
// load this from wherever you want
const html = `
  <!-- your external scripts and styles go here -->
  <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
  <script>
    const stripe = Stripe('{STRIPE_KEY}');
    /**
     * STRIPE IMPLEMENTATION GOES HERE
     */
    // Once we've got a token we send it back to our app
    stripe.createToken(/*{STRIPE_CARD}*/).then(({ token }) =>
      parent.postMessage({ type: 'stripe-token', token }, '*'));
  </script>
`;

// wait for the frame to load then write our body
iframe.addEventListener('load', () =>
  iframe.contentWindow.document.write(html));
}

// add our iframe to the page and Stripe.js will load (and start pinging its server!)
document.body.append(iframe);

// wait for confirmation from the frame that we're finished with Stripe.js (see the html snippet above)
window.addEventListener('message', ({ data }) => {
  if (data.type === 'stripe-token') {
    console.log(data.token);

    // we've got a token! We can remove our frame (and unload Stripe.js and all its telemetry!)
    if (hasSrcdoc) iframe.srcdoc = '';
    else iframe.src = '';
    document.body.removeChild(iframe);
  }
});
```

Full details here: https://codepen.io/theprojectsomething/full/ExVNEoZ