# What is this stripe request and why is it firing multiple times?

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments

For a laravel application that uses stripe, this request `https://r.stripe.com/0` gets fired multiple times like so:

[image: screenshot of the network section]

These requests got fired right after I refreshed the homepage.
The problem is that I recently got a `429 too many requests` error in my live server. This is pretty rare but I suspect it has something to do with stripe since I read about rate-limiting in stripe.
Since I am new to stripe and I got this project handed over midway, I had some questions:

1. Is there any relation between the 429 error and these stripe requests? Or is this something to do with the way the system is built?
2. If it's the former, how would one resolve the issue? Maybe disable the security checks (cause I read somewhere that these requests were stripe security checks), or maybe increase the rate limit from stripe in some way?

I searched extensively about this but couldn't find any relevant posts anywhere, maybe because it's a very trivial problem. I would be grateful if someone who has faced this or knows about this can enlighten me.

Comment: yes these comes when using stripe but server didnot give error of too many request in my case.. you can talk with your server provider

Comment: AFAIK those requests are related to Stripe's fraud detection stuff.  Some more info here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45718026/stripe-js-making-duplicate-requests-new-requests-on-state-change But these requests are going from your browser to stripe.com - they don't touch your server, and can not influence your server sending you a 429.

Comment: That is correct, the r.stripe.com calls are for Stripe fraud detection and should be hitting Stripe's server. Can you post more info about the 429 error Aadesh? With more info on where you are seeing it and what errors it caused, you may be able to get better help/direction on this post.

Comment: I have this problem

Comment: Thanks guys, the problem was with how the frontend system (built on React) fired API requests. As far as I'm concerned, these multiple stripe requests are not in any way harmful to your system.