# Stripe.js CORS error flooding console in React app

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments

I have implemented @stripe/react-stripe-js and @stripe/stripe-js in my React App and although all the payments are successfull in test environment, the console is flooded with errors as per below:

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://r.stripe.com/0. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed). Status code: (null).

Should I be ignoring these as the payments work and why is stripe not handling CORS on their servers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From looking at similar questions on Stackoverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72272037/what-is-this-stripe-request-and-why-is-it-firing-multiple-times?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74517735/spring-security-prevents-requests-to-stripe-cors-blocking-issue), `r.stripe.com` is just for tracking metrics and it should not have any impact on the ability to make payments. For this reason, you can ignore these errors you see on your console.